# Manual string 'in' function doesn't work if substring is at the end of the word

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, substring, manual

I'm trying to manually code the python string `in` function for an assignment. Using this code, where `s` is the string and `t` is the substring I am trying to find:

```
def test(s, t):
    stidx = 0
    while stidx < len(s):
        idx = 0
        for i in s[stidx:]:
            if idx < len(t):
                if t[idx] == i:
                    idx += 1
                    continue
                else:
                    break
            if idx == len(t):
                return True
        stidx += 1
    return False
```

The above code works, except when I am checking a substring at the very end of the word (e.g. `s = 'happy'` and `t = 'py'`). If I add an arbitrary character to the end of `s`, it works. Why is this?

Comment: Just delete `continue` and it will work.

Comment: Sometimes walking through your code on paper helps or you can watch it execute at http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit.

Answer (score 0):

maybe?

```
def test(s, t):
    """
    :param s:   exp: happy
    :param t:   exp: py
    :return:
    """
    tmp = result = 0
    t_len = len(t)
    while tmp <= len(s)-t_len:
        if s[tmp: tmp+t_len] == t:
            result = 1
            break
        else:
            tmp += 1
            continue

    return bool(result)
```